# Determine front page for specific language

Tags: i18n-l10n

I'm using [I18n](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) and I am trying to choose which front page to use for each language.

I actually get the following message for every page :

> The requested page "/en" could not be found.

Same for /de (deutch).
Has anyone met this problem before ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. It was in "Administration » Configuration » System" that I didn't set the default front page !